# C# CefSharp wpf cant locate dependecies

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I have simple wpf application that using CefSharp with initializing settings cache path:

```
try
{
    var settings = new CefSettings();
    settings.CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Cache");
    Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

It works well, but i am using this code to start up when system starts:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
key.SetValue(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

And if app is started by system on startup i get this error in catch block:

```
System.Exception: Unable to lacte requred Cef/CefSharp dependencies:
Missing:CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
Missing:CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.Core.dll
Missing:CefSharp.Core.dll
Missing:icudtl.dat
Missing:libcef.dll
```

But when i run app manualy it works well.
Thanks!

Comment: It's because you haven't set working directory for startup key in registry.

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad And can you help me? - Where may i set working dir?

Comment: So i found solution: `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);` - Add berfore initializing. Thanks @AliBahraminezhad

Comment: I'm glad I'd helped. I wrote an answer here. Perhaps it'll help other people in future. Don't forget to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `working directory` is not the bin directory of your application.

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
key.SetValue(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

There are lots of way to change current directory to the bin path of your app. The easiest way is to change current directory within your code ( as you suggested ).

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain‌​.BaseDirectory);
```